# Quickly switch input methods (swype->other)

Tags: keyboard, swype, input-methods

I'd like to be able to switch from Swype to Hacker Keyboard from within programs, especially ConnectBot and TerminalEmulator.  Hacker Keyboard comes with a shortcut to switch to others, but Swype doesn't.  If there are workarounds to reduce the number of clicks needed to switch input methods, those would also be welcome.

Comment: Long-pressing an input field generally prompts you for the Input method.

Answer (score 2):

I am looking at Swype right now, and it's got a cogweel in the bottom left corner, which if pressed for more than 1 second gives you a choice of the input methods (Swype, Android Keyboard, others...)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Jg4v.png

Comment: Mine doesn't have a cogwheel... is this a version issue?

Comment: Could be. I downloaded the latest version, to be able to type in 3 different languages. I currently run 3.23.

Comment: http://www.apktop.com/swype-3-23-multi-language.html as seen in the first screenshot, the same button that has the cogweel on my app, is situated in the upper left corner, and has the (i) sign. Could be related to anything. Swype version/Firmware/Resolution...

Comment: I'm apparently on 3.25, though it looks like that's not the problem, since the screenshot you pointed to also has the (i) instead of a cogwheel.